# When starting up phantomjs from node using the node-phantom bridge, the cookies from node are not being passed over properly. Anybody know why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

Basically, I start off using node, and then I startup phantomjs.
To take the cookies from node to phantom I code:

```
page.set('phantomcookies', nodecookiejar, callback);
```

But when I checked the cookies, there were so many more phantomjs cookies
than node cookies. Then, I coded:

```
page.clearCookies(function(err){
    page.set('phantomcookies', nodecookiejar, callback);
}
```

The callback obviously is so that the program runs in proper order. But,
I still some extra phantomjs cookies, which I find is really confusing 
since phantomjs is merely supposed to copy the cookies from node through the
node-phantom-simple bridge (as far as I know). Any ideas would help.
Thank you.